Clash between breakable tcolorbox with tikz externalize
I have a custom theorem-like environment created using tcolorbox. The environment may need to encompass many pages, so I am using the breakable option when creating it. However, I noticed an error when I use the environment while externalization (from the tikz package) is enabled. Please see the example below:
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable,theorems}  
\newtcbtheorem[number within=chapter]{mydemonstration}{Demonstration}{%
    breakable,
    }{demo}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\chapter{My chapter}

%\tikzexternaldisable
\begin{mydemonstration}{Test proof}{test-proof}
    \blindtext[7]

\end{mydemonstration}
%\tikzexternalenable

\end{document}

Running this code leads to several error messages (in Overleaf). This appears to only occur if the environment spans multiple pages; if it does not, then it compiles fine. Moreover, if I enclose the custom environment between \tikzexternaldisable and \tikzexternalenable, then it also compiles, but I find this to be quite inelegant. Is there another solution?

You could use the shield externalize option to protect your tcolorbox from getting externalised:
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable,theorems}  
\newtcbtheorem[number within=chapter]{mydemonstration}{Demonstration}{%
    breakable,
    shield externalize
    }{demo}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\chapter{My chapter}

\begin{mydemonstration}{Test proof}{test-proof}
    \blindtext[7]

\end{mydemonstration}

\end{document}

(if you have different types of tcolorboxes in your document, you could use \tcbset{shield externalize} to protect all of them)
